# NAudio how to capture audio data from MMDevice as if it was playing at max volume

Tags: c#, winforms, naudio

ive been searching for a way to try to properly capture the sound that is currently playing through the default "speakers" of the pc and make a visualizer out of it.

Thats where NAudio comes in:

```
MMDevice[] AudioDevices = new MMDeviceEnumerator().EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.All, DeviceState.Active).ToArray();
foreach (MMDevice device in AudioDevices)
{
    string deviceType = device.DataFlow == DataFlow.Capture ? "INPUT" : "OUTPUT";
    string deviceLabel = $"{deviceType}: {device.FriendlyName}";
    deviceLabels.Add(deviceLabel);
}
var enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
var default_device = enumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Render, Role.Console);

MMDevice selectedDevice = AudioDevices[0];
AudioDevice = selectedDevice.DataFlow == DataFlow.Render ? new WasapiLoopbackCapture(selectedDevice) : new WasapiCapture(selectedDevice, true, 10);
AudioDevice.DataAvailable += WaveIn_DataAvailable;
```

Capturing the audio values i use the following event:

```
private void WaveIn_DataAvailable(object? sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
        {
            int bytesPerSamplePerChannel = AudioDevice.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample / 8;
            int bytesPerSample = bytesPerSamplePerChannel * AudioDevice.WaveFormat.Channels;
            int bufferSampleCount = e.Buffer.Length / bytesPerSample;

            if (bufferSampleCount >= AudioValues.Length)
            {
                bufferSampleCount = AudioValues.Length;
            }

            if (bytesPerSamplePerChannel == 2 && AudioDevice.WaveFormat.Encoding == WaveFormatEncoding.Pcm)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < bufferSampleCount; i++)
                    AudioValues[i] = BitConverter.ToInt16(e.Buffer, i * bytesPerSample);
            }
            else if (bytesPerSamplePerChannel == 4 && AudioDevice.WaveFormat.Encoding == WaveFormatEncoding.Pcm)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < bufferSampleCount; i++)
                    AudioValues[i] = BitConverter.ToInt32(e.Buffer, i * bytesPerSample);
            }
            else if (bytesPerSamplePerChannel == 4 && AudioDevice.WaveFormat.Encoding == WaveFormatEncoding.IeeeFloat)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < bufferSampleCount; i++)
                    AudioValues[i] = BitConverter.ToSingle(e.Buffer, i * bytesPerSample);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException(AudioDevice.WaveFormat.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Lastly, I then use a FFT library to then convert the audio values to a new array using FFTmagnitude Transformation and then process them further to get my visualizer but this is out of scope of the problem im facing.

The problem i have is that the audio data array outputed from the WaveIn_DataAvailable event is dependant of the "speakers" volume, so if the volume is for example at 2%, the audio values im getting are much lower than if the volume was at 100%.

Strangely if the volume is muted or 0% the audio values are as high as 100%.

What i would like to get instead is, regardless of the volume level to always get the audio values as if it was 100%.

I couldnt find any way to get the audio values this way, there has to be something very obvious or simple that im missing but so far i couldnt find any example or suggestion on how to achieve this.

Comment: I would try with WASAPI instead.

Comment: Greetings thanks for your reply, could you please elaborate? I tought my example already included wasapi.

Comment: start control mmsys.cpl, play something, turn off volume on your keyboard, see that device that still plays at full volume? this is the one you want to capture through wasapi.

Comment: Hello there, thank you for your reply, that might be what im looking for, could you please post an example? It would help me alot

Comment: What you have to look for is on whether a device is a loopback or not: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/loopback-recording

Comment: For some reason, in my mind, what you're suggesting still semms to be exactly what im doing, please post a working code example as i did in my thread so i can fully understand the differences. Thank you in advance!